Korean movie where wife gets tempted to join a brothel
This is kind of a long shot I suppose however I have literally searched everywhere.
About 2 years ago, I watched a Korean drama film where a man and woman were married (woman being the main character). This woman was bored with her life and constantly left alone. She ends up meeting this woman who is supposedly a hooker or brothel worker of some sort who slowly encourages her to take on that life and tries to show her how exciting it is, which she begins to do in secret, and at one point begins to enjoy it.  I specifically remember a scene involving the wife (after starting to become happier) dance around her home throwing the clothes she had now gotten all over the place.
The ending involves the brothel worker woman revealing to the main character that her husband actually visits the brothel almost every day and that's why he's never home, him being a normal client of hers. She reveals all of this while having sex with the husband right in front of the wife. The wife separates the two and locks the brothel worker out of the room. The brothel worker begins to pound on the door demanding she get paid over and over again until she finally does when she leaves the 2 to figure this all out. However I can't seem to remember past that.
The best i can place it is between 2010 and 2014 possibly early 15. It was placed as a Drama
